# Jquery console.log and name attach not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a [plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) to give my `<select>` elements images loaded by jquery. The thing is, the names are not transferring to the new code's `<input>` elements, and thus cannot submit the form surrounding it.

The plugin turns this code:

```
<select id="itemselect1" name="item1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option selected>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>
<select id="itemselect2" name="item3">
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option selected>C</option>
</select>
```

Into: (I simplified it a bit)

```
<div id="itemselect1" name="item1" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" value="2" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="itemselect2" name="item2" class="dd-container">
    <div class="dd-select">
        <input class="dd-selected-value" value="C" type="hidden">
    </div>
</div>  // the list continues
```

So I tried this approach to transfer the names over:

```
var list = {
  "itemselect1": "item1",
  "itemselect2": "item2",
  "itemselect3": "item3",
  "itemselect4": "item4",
  "itemselect5": "item5",
  "itemselect6": "item6"
};
$.each( list, function( key, value ) {
  $("#"+ key).children().children("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", value );
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);       
  console.log($("div#"+ key).attr("name"));   // To diagnose why it isnt working
});
```

And the console just reads:

```
itemselect1 (index):32
item1 (index):33
undefined (index):34
itemselect2 (index):32
item2 (index):33
undefined (index):34
```

Regardless if I use the plugin or now, the names aren't getting attached somehow. Please help, Thanks.

Comment: use prop instead of attr

Comment: Replace console.log($("div#"+ key).attr("name"));   By console.log($("#"+ key).attr("name"));    Remove div from  code.

Comment: @Amit: `prop` is for enabled/disabled/… states, not for standard attributes.

Comment: @SujitPaitil, I've tried that as well with the same result.

Comment: Can you make a running sample with the stackoverflox code snippet or jsfiddle ?

Comment: you are not assigning the name to the `div` so `console.log($("div#"+ key).attr("name"));` won't work you need `console.log($("#"+ key).children().children("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name"));`

Comment: looks fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z096gumo/1/

Comment: Wow. I have no clue then. I used the plugin with the fiddle and it works fine too. When I try to mess with it on my site it just shows the `name="item1"` for all the elements.

Comment: When I recreate the fiddle on my site it doesn't work.

Comment: Call me stupid but I would pay to get this crap fixed. It's undoubtedly a stupid mistake but GOOD GOD is it frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

use `find`() in jquery. you assigned name attribute to input but you print and check the parent div name so it gives undefined.

```
$.each( list, function( key, value ) {
  $("#"+ key).find(".dd-select input.dd-selected-value").attr("name", value);  
  console.log($("#"+ key).find("input.dd-selected-value").attr("name"));   
});
```

Comment: That still comes up as undefined.